# mySQL - Apply a row level lock using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, locking, innodb

Using PHP's mysqli how do you apply a row level lock?

Row level locks stop anyone editing currently present rows that match your criteria right? but do they stop a user inserting a row which matches your criteria?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to lock a specific row from editing, use `FOR UPDATE` at the end of a SELECT query. this locks the row in your transaction and prevents other users from updating it. this only works in transactional storage engines like innodb.

in answer to your questions, yes, row level locks "stop anyone editing currently present rows that match your criteria". more specifically, if (inside a transaction) you INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE a row, that row is locked from editing by anyone else until your COMMIT your transaction. if you SELECT a row using `FOR UPDATE` then that also locks the row.

however, this does not "stop a user inserting a row which matches your criteria".

Comment: It should be stressed that row level locking is only available in InnoDB and not MyISAM.

Comment: Ah, just seen the innodb tag on this :)

Comment: IF Row is locked is it possible to select data from that row ? for example if row is locked so can i able to fetch data by `fetch_object()` ?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you're trying to achieve? The InnoDB engine uses [row level locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) but this is an automatic internal MySQL process.