# Resource access lock PHP

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I am developing a simple support application where clients ask questions and admins answer them.  I need to implement a resource lock for a question to avoid multiple admins working on same question and avoid data collision.  What are best practices for this kind of task?

PS I am using PHP and MySQL base to store questions.

**Edit**

I know that i just simply could put a state field to that resource and when opened ill lock it but how do i close it if lets say admin just closes the browser window.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729457/mysql-apply-a-row-level-lock-using-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... if you have your questions in Mysql db how to just add one column with info who is working on this problem? You could then check it when admin wants to open question...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to your lock column add, you probably should lock the entry as soon as someone request for READ it, not just when the admin attrib it to himself.
If you do this, you'll avoid simultaneous access to the ressource.

For exemple, if you've got your UI which is displaying something like:

/!\ WARNING /!\ Another administrator already handle this issue /!\ WARNING /!\

you'll probably want to avoid two administrator accessing the request at the same time, using a lock set as soon as the UI is requesting the GET STATUS / GET INFORMATION (SELECT request) of the issue.

If your looking for a temporary lock, you'll have to deal with session and triggers AND reusable key.

Comment: Can explain a bit more about 'If your looking for a temporary lock, you'll have to deal with session and triggers AND reusable key.' As I would like to create a temporary lock